# Getting time of day from user for silly simple app

Tags: python-3.x, input, time, formatting

I am begginer in Python and I wanted to try to make myslef a simple piece of code that would take my input of time when I came to work and tell me when I get to go home.

Problem is the input formatting and then adding those 8 hours of work into it and having an output.

I can make it work with integers but that is not good enough. I would like to see `HH:MM` format in I/O

I searched all around the web but what I found are mostly articles and advice about time in general (date and more importantly, the datetime.now) whereas I need it to understand I want to input time when I came to work and time when I get to leave the work, regardless of day and so on.

```
# When do I get to go home program
# first we need ot define a variable to use it to store the time when I came 
# to work
# That is atw (arrived to work)
# gh is "go home"

from datetime import time
atw = input ("When I came to work in format of HH:MM \n")
#atw = datetime.strptime(input('enter time you arrived to work in HHMM format: '), "%H%M")
h,m = map (int, time.split(":"))
#gh = atw (hour = h, minute = m)
print (("I came to work @", atw ,"%H%M"))

gh = atw + 0800  
print ("You can go home @ ", gh)
```

All sort of error messages, from syntax to problems with format of my input and adding of those 8 hours of work to the final number (`gh` variable)

Is there some awesome being that could walk me trough how do I actually make python to understand that I am adding time to variable that should be formatted as time (`HH:MM`) input which is coming form user?

Comment: What was the problem with using `strptime`? That seemed like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\Playground\", line 9, in <module>
    atw = datetime.strptime(input('enter time you arrived to work in HHMM format: '), "%H%M")
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined


                      I am sorry if this is stupid, but I might just not understand how to type or use it correctly

Comment: You have to either use `import datetime` and then use `datetime.strptime`, or `from datetime import strptime` and then use `strptime` (without `datetime.`).

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's do this step by step, because as you said, there *All sort of error messages, from syntax to...*

```
from datetime import time
atw = input ("When I came to work in format of HH:MM \n")
```

These first two lines work without problem, that's fine.

```
h,m = map (int, time.split(":"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'split'
```

Oh, an error, let's read what the error message says: *type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'split'*. Well, that's correct, because we don't want to split `time`, but the time that we gave to input and that has the name `atw`, so let's use that:

```
h,m = map (int, atw.split(":"))
print (("I came to work @", atw ,"%H%M"))
```

No error, but a weird output:

> ('I came to work @', '08:17', '%H%M')

You probably didn't want a tuple as output (the parentheses) and wanted to format that output, as I can see from the format string `"%H%M"`. Fortunately python (>=3.6) has a nice solution for that called [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498):

```
print (f"I came to work @{atw}")
```

Hmmm, wait, what about the formatting, that just outputs what we inputed... So make use of `h` and `m`:

```
print (f"I came to work @{h:02d}:{m:02d}")
```

Do a google search what that `:02d` means and what other options there are ;)
Next line:

```
gh = atw + 0800  
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    gh = atw + 0800  
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Hmmm, you want to add 8 hours to get the endtime, but all you get is an syntax error... That's because `0800` is no valid python construct, you probably ment just 8? Let's try this...

```
gh = atw + 8  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Another error, but why? You are using atw, which is a string, albeit you already split that in two ints `h` and `m`, with h representing the hours:

```
gh = h + 8
print ("You can go home @ ", gh)
```

Ahh, damn that print again. Look above and use f-strings:

```
print (f"You can go home @{gh}:{m}")
```

And now try to see if you get a solution using `strptime` as @mkrieger1 suggested in the comments.
And pleeeeease do a python tutorial :)

Comment: I cant thank you enough, already full steam ahead into P4E with Chuck Severance, its great, just learning it bit by bit, this one was little bit too complicated with the formats of time I suppose, but this sure helped a lot to understand what it is about. Thank you again for the help and have a great day!